# Real-time CSS editing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor

Is there a plugin for jQuery or generally a method to have a `textarea` containing CSS code of the currently open web page which will be automatically updated during edit (without page reload)?

Comment: Just simple textarea + inserting the code from this textarea to `style` tag directly, wouldn't be the simplest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys – most of all thanks to takeshin (who posted a comment to my original question).

takeshin's comment helped me quite a bit: With jQuery, I inserted the edited CSS code from a code highlighter called [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) into the head of the page. It's as simple as that. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not *exactly* a general solution you're asking for, so just throwing this out there in case it's what you're ultimately after.  If your goal is to edit and play with your styles there's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or Chrome's [built-in developer tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial#elements).

The JavaScript version is [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about this one – but I'm rather looking for something like a CSS sandbox. Firebug Lite isn't customizable, the solution should be more flexible because I need to integrate it into a CMS.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think there's a "general"/"pluggable" one out there since it's such a highly specialized thing, tweaking specific styles like themeroller does maybe, but that's about it...sorry that answer sucks, but I don't think what you're looking for exists, at least as a pluign, but hopefully someone *has* seen this and proves me wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

There are now several services out there. I personally use [codr.io](http://codr.io). For not-quite real-time I use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).